# Shared resources concurrency in project reactor

Tags: multithreading, project-reactor, spring-webflow

Let's say that I have a stream of objects, that I process and ultimately persist to a db.
That stream could be "never ending", message subscription for an example.

And during that processing I wish to implement some aggregation as a side effect.
For an example, let's say there is a shared resource for the global processing count.
There is one counter per subscription (essentially per Flux stream), **but also a shared one**.

How can I access that shared resource in a safe and performant way?
I must stress that this shared resource should be accessible at "all" times.

If it were an imperative approach, I'd spin a thread pool / executors and route messages based on say id.
Those counters can be then thread local variables, and I need not bother with concurrency.
Or something like that.

As far as I know, the threading model does not guarantee that all operations will be executed on the same thread.